# XSLT - XML to HTML trasform - Create nested <div> from one level elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml file like follows,

```
<doc>
    <para>111111111111</para>
    <!--start div1-->
    <para>2222222</para>
    <para>3333333</para>
    <!--start div2-->
    <para>4444444</para>
    <para>5555555</para>
    <para>6666666</para>
    <!--start div3-->
    <para>7777777</para>
    <para>8888888</para>
    <!--end div3-->
    <para>9999999</para>
    <para>1010110</para>
    <!--end div2-->
    <para>11,11,11</para>
    <para>12,12,12,</para>
    <!--end div1-->
    <para>13,13,13</para>
</doc>
```

I'm doing an XSLT transform form this input and I need to put these elements on nested `<div>` elements. The comments are added from the previous stage to identify where the `<div>` elements should go. In the given example there are three nested `div` element are there but it can be varied. My expected output is,

```
<doc>
    <para>111111111111</para>
    <div>
        <!--start div1-->
        <para>2222222</para>
        <para>3333333</para>
        <div>
            <!--start div2-->
            <para>4444444</para>
            <para>5555555</para>
            <para>6666666</para>
            <div>
                <!--start div3-->
                <para>7777777</para>
                <para>8888888</para>
                <!--end div3-->
            </div>
            <para>9999999</para>
            <para>1010110</para>
            <!--end div2-->
        </div>
        <para>11,11,11</para>
        <para>12,12,12,</para>
        <!--end div1-->
    </div>
    <para>13,13,13</para>
</doc>
```

I cannot write three nested `<for-each>` group as these nested `<div>` elements can be varied in other inputs. (Can go to nested level four or five etc..).

I've tried following way but it only adds first `<div>` elements only,

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
        <doc>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*|comment()" group-adjacent="
                if (self::comment())
                then
                substring-after(self::comment(),' ')
                else
                local-name()">

                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="*">
                    <div id="{local-name()}-{position()}">   
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />      
                    </div>    
                </xsl:for-each-group>  

            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </doc>

    </xsl:template>
```

can anyone suggest me a method to implement these nested `<div>` elements? or how can I recursively call `<for-each>` in XSLT?

Comment: If the "previous step" added the comments as you say, why cannot the previous step just insert the `<div>` elements instead?  The question is unclear.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I'm doing single source publishing from XML data. My original source XML has these content as nested content. In step one, I transform this into different xml which normalize all nested content to one level (easy to handle in PDF, EPUB publishing). This second XML is my middle file and I use this middle xml file for source publishing as different formats (PDF, EPUB..ect). But in this specific scenario, I need to publish HTML as well. So that's why I need to re-nested this one level elements.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just a broken workflow.  You are making extra problems for yourself.  By un-nesting nested content you are discarding information.  Re-architect your workflow to let you branch just before the PDF/EPUB and HTML renderings, so you don't have to re-nest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the recursion in a template or function, the following is a function as it allows a more compact syntax:

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="node()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$input" group-starting-with="comment()[. = 'start div' || $level]">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="self::comment()[. = 'start div' || $level]">
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="comment()[. = 'end div' || $level]">
                      <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::comment()[. = 'end div' || $level]]">
                              <div>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                                  <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()[not(position() = (1, last()))], $level + 1)"/>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
                              </div>                              
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>
```

Full example is (XSLT 3 but for XSLT 2 you would just need to replace the use of the `||` operator with `concat` calls):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="node()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$input" group-starting-with="comment()[. = 'start div' || $level]">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="self::comment()[. = 'start div' || $level]">
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="comment()[. = 'end div' || $level]">
                      <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::comment()[. = 'end div' || $level]]">
                              <div>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                                  <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group()[not(position() = (1, last()))], $level + 1)"/>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
                              </div>                              
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(node(), 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzt

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment()[.='start div1' or .='start div2' or .='start div3' or .='end div3' or  .='end div2' or .='end div1']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". ='start div1'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--start div1--&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". ='start div2'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--start div2--&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". ='start div3'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--start div3--&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". ='end div3'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--end div3--&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". ='end div2'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--end div2--&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". ='end div1'">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--end div1--&gt;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div&gt;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
You may try like this
```